# How can I reply a going thread to a specific group of emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

1. I am using Google App Scripts to search and reply to a going emails.
2. Let's say I can use GmailApp.search to search a thread by subject already and I want to reply to the first search result
3. I want to reply to: and cc: to specific people every time search and reply this going email. Like: to: a@gmail.com + cc: b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com.
4. Now I am using thread[0].replyAll because I don't know how to do as above. But always it reply to all the people of the last message of the going email ( even including me in to the cc or me in the to: if I am the last one doing message of the total email)

   var subjectsearch =brandname+"/ SAMBU"+"/ MATERIAL REQUEST/ ROUND "+round+'/ '+subjectname;
   var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:('+subjectsearch+')');
   if (threads.length>0){
             threads[0].replyAll(messagePrefix,{from:"kevin@sambu.sewing.co.kr",htmlBody: message, })

[first message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuh5J.png)
[If I replyall it will look like this, I dont want to send to me but always a specific to: and cc: if I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb7rH.png)

Comment: Add a sample of your script so that we can see what you've already got and add to it where required.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/56104505/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 did you know about google-apps-script ? If yes, just follow all points as in question you will get exactly what [Kevin Ngo] wants      .......